# I can't drag a program in Citrix to my second monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, citrix

I have a two monitor setup.  When I launch Citrix it will only run on my Primary monitor.  I can run on either of my two monitors, but it has to be changed to primary.  I have an NVIDIA card GTX 470.  The start menu is setup to display only on the first screen.

I tried a fix I found online where I switch my primary monitor and match the resolutions.  This only changed the problem.  Instead, the desktop background (normally hidden) shows up stretched across both monitors.  It treats my dual monitors as a single monitor and stretches.  I even ran a program I wrote in .NET and it says # of monitors detected = 1.

Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an old version of Citrix Receiver.  Installing version 12.1 fixed the issue.